# what's the difference between 会, 可以, and 能?

Tags: grammar

Are they used interchangeably or do they really have separate uses? I keep getting confused between the three.

Comment: No, they are not interchangeable. It would require a whole book chapter to answer your question in detail. And your question has been posted before, refer to: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/253/how-do-i-decide-whether-to-use-%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5-%E4%BC%9A-or-%E8%83%BD

Comment: short answer: 会 relate to knowledge; 可以 relate to principles or laws; 能 related to ability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have pretty similar meaning and almost interchangeable in daily conversation but there are subtle differences between these three words.

- 可以 means you can do something
- 能 is used when you want to emphasise you have the ability to do something
- 会 means you are not only able to do it but do it proficiently

There are a few examples:

- 我可以说中文 I can speak Chinese (probably not very well and maybe not willing to speak Chinese)
- 我能说中文 I am able to speak Chinese (I'm not those people who completely don't understand Chinese)
- 我会说中文 I can speak Chinese proficiently (probably you can speak Chinese fluently and you're willing to speak Chinese)

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Very good answer, upvote!