# How to say "can/can’t use" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, mandarin

How can I say “my wechat is not working, I can only use alipay.”
Is this right?
我的微信坏了， 我只用支付宝。
I wanted to know what are the other ways to say can or can’t use?

Comment: "X is not working" -> X 不能用了

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/253/25265， https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Comparing_%22hui,%22_%22neng,%22_%22keyi%22

Answer (score 2):

我的微信**用不了了**，我只能用支付宝。

我的微信**不能用了**，我只能用支付宝。

我的微信**没法用了**，我只能用支付宝。

我的微信**有问题**，我只能用支付宝。

我的微信**有点问题**，我只能用支付宝。

Answer (score 1):

You should say 我的微信坏了， 我只"能"用支付宝。

我只用支付宝 means you use 支付寶 ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

My WeChat is not working (dunno why), I can only use Alipay.
我的微信用不了了（不知道为什么），我只能使用支付宝。

微信好了的话，请给我发红包吧。